# Placeholders for parts doesn't honor the closeable flag?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

I'm running into a strange issue in an application I'm developing using the Eclipse RCP platform.

In my model, I'm attempting to use `Shared Elements` in order to reuse parts between perspectives. I created a `Label` part and ensured that the `Closeable` flag was off.

[image: Label part]

I created a placeholder for this part and ensured that the same `Closeable` flag was also off for the placeholder.[image: Label placeholder].

However, when I run my RCP application (with persisted state cleared, of course), my part has the close icon on it and can indeed be closed.

[image: RCP application with placeholders]

On the other hand, if I place the part directly within my part stack as follows, [image: Label part directly under partstack]

and leave the `Closeable` flag off, the part displays correctly without the close icon. [image: RCP application without placeholder]

**How can I get the placeholders to honor the closeable flag?** Or is this the intended behavior...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is supposed to work but doesn't. This is reported in Eclipse bug [400771](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=400771).

This is currently still open. The target for a fix is Eclipse 4.7 but I guess it has missed that as the first release candidate for 4.7 is already available without it.